# ng2-popover change css/background color of entire popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have an Angular2 app and I am using the ng2-popover module found [here](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-popover). Here is some example code I am using:

```
<popover-content #myPopover 
            title="Popover title" 
            placement="bottom"
            [animation]="true" 
            [closeOnClickOutside]="true" style="background-color: red">
                <b>Very</b> <span style="color: #C21F39">Dynamic</span> <span style="color: #00b3ee">Reusable</span>
                <b><i><span style="color: #ffc520">Popover With</span></i></b> <small>Html support</small>.
</popover-content>
```

I know how to change the style of the content (as I have done in the example) but how do I change the style of the whole popover itself such as the `background-color` and the `box-shadow`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of the [**special selectors**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors) for this:

```
:host /deep/ .popover {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FhUxumgHzAIKMJsOEa7S?p=preview)